# Word for how well something actually works

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

It's a one word term that means how well something actually works??

Different from something that works well, it's like.. imagine shopping for bras:

> Some people buy bras based on looks, but some people don't value looks over *{blank}*.

(Meaning how well it supports, and all that.)

I think it starts with a c but I could be wrong.

Comment: It starts with an 'f'.  See below.

Comment: No, it starts with a *c*. See below.

Comment: In that particular situation, I'd say *...but some don't value looks over [**fit**](https://www.wacoal-america.com/main/our-solutions/bra-fit-guide.htm)*. Or even, *comfort*.

Comment: [How many letters?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity?cb=1).

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "*how well something actually works*" in your first sentence being "*Different from something that works well*" in your second sentence?

Comment: Mechanics, perhaps?

Comment: ***Quality***...?

Comment: Initially, just reading the question, I thought 'practicality'.

Comment: You're probably looking for **comfort** but that's not about how well it works but rather how good it fits the person.

Answer (score 26):

> **function**
>
> noun
>
> the kind of action or activity proper to a person, thing, or
> institution; the purpose for which something is designed or exists;
> role.
>
> [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/function?s=t)

---

This **edit** is from AndyT's comment. It gives you another noun to use that more closely matches the requested usage of qualifying whether or not something is working as designed. And from the discussion in the comments, I now prefer **functionality** over **function**.

> **functionality**
>
> noun
>
> 1 The quality of being suited to serve a purpose well; practicality.
> ‘I like the feel and functionality of this bakeware’
>
> 1.1 The purpose that something is designed or expected to fulfil.
>
> [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/functionality)

---

This **edit** also stems from the comments and discussion. It provides different parts of speech to use in sentences that are structured for such.

> **function**
>
> verb (used without object)
>
> 8. to perform a specified action or activity; **work; operate**: The computer isn't functioning now. He rarely functions before noon.
> 9. to have or exercise a function; serve: In earlier English the present tense often functioned as a future. This orange crate can
>    function as a chair.
>
> [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/function?s=t)

---

> **functional**
>
> adjective
>
> 1. of or relating to a function or functions : functional difficulties in the administration.
> 2. capable of operating or functioning : When will the ventilating system be functional again?
> 3. having or serving a utilitarian purpose; **capable of serving the purpose for which it was designed**
>
> [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/functional?s=t)

---

Common usages of these words in everyday speech:

"This phone is ugly, but I love its functionality."

"How well does this computer function?" "It is old, so not well."

"Your brand new Ford breaks down all the time. I drive an '85 Dodge, but at least it's functional."

Comment: **Form follows function** is a design principle that places function first before aesthetics.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_follows_function

Comment: This is a good answer, lacking only a source and a link (if possible) to the source.  The definition in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/function) is close to the definition you quoted, but not exactly the same.  Please add your source.  I'm upvoting because I am confident you will. :)

Comment: Also "functionality" would work well in the OP's sentence.

Comment: @thomj1332 the opposite principle is also alliterative: _style over substance._

Comment: The issue with this is that function isn't actually an exact fit.  Function is a description of what something does, how it does it, but not how well it does a particular task.  In the case of the bras, one that is uncomfortable and falls apart the moment you move but has built in health checking, water cooling, gps location, self cleaning robots, and so on has significantly more function than one that just provides good support and comfort.

Comment: @Shades that's exactly my point, the purpose for which something is designed is entirely dependent one what the specific designer actually wants to accomplish.  If the purpose is to demonstrate advances in wearable medical technology then a bra with a heart rate monitor is fulfilling that design goal.  Apply the logic to a car or phone, both of which have radically different function footprints from their single original purpose of moving things and relaying voice, respectively, over a distance.

Comment: @Shades because function is about whether it can do something, not how good it is at doing it.

Comment: @Kaithar OK, I don't completely disagree with you. I do think people use the word (even in noun form) to mean how well something works. I've edited my answer to include the verb form as well as "functional," the adjective form.

Comment: @Shades hmm, true, functional does have a closer meaning, but with a rather important difference.  Something that is in a "100% functional" operational state means that it is in working order without implying how well it works.  Two brand new cars of different models are likely to be equally functional while not of equal performance characteristics.

Answer (score 12):

Consider *efficacy*.

> **efficacy** *noun*
>   The ability to produce a desired or intended result.
>   ‘there is little information on the efficacy of this treatment’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/efficacy)

Your example would then be:

- Some people buy bras based on looks, but some people don't value looks over efficacy.

Comment: efficacy or quality

Comment: @Xanne *Efficacy* is related to how well it works; *quality* relates more to how good it is.

Comment: Efficacy is a perfect word for this use and is usually used in the context of drug function when discussing how good a particular substance is at achieving a goal.

Comment: @Lawrence: an example would be groceries. The store brand will almost invariably get the job done (just as effective/efficacious), but may not be of as fine a quality as a fancier brand.

Comment: @MathieuK. Since you're the second person to talk about *efficiacy* vs *quality*, it might be me that's missing something here. I thought the OP was looking for a word that describes how well the job was done, rather than the quality of the item. Are you saying this isn't the case? (It's a genuine question on my part.)

Comment: "Efficiency" may be a more familiar word that carries the same meaning for most people.

Comment: @brichins There is a [difference](http://writingexplained.org/efficacy-vs-efficiency-difference), though. *Efficacy* has to do with whether (or even how much) something is effective in accomplishing a particular job, while *efficiency* has to do with the cost (however defined) of doing it.

Comment: @Lawrence, no I'm agreeing with you, and providing an example of why, upon reflection, *quality* isn't quite right.

Comment: @Lawrence agreed, there is a clear difference; I was referring to `efficiency` including the concept of "[competency in performance](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/efficiency)". Efficacy is certainly the more precise word, but anyone alive today is [significantly less likely](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=efficiency%2Cefficacy%2C+effectiveness) to be familiar with it;  "`effectiveness`" is probably the best intermediate choice for strictness of definition and familiarity to the average English speaker.

Comment: @brichins efficiency is fundamentally a measurement of waste though.  If I have two fuels that can be converted to mechanical energy with 90% and 50% efficiency it doesn't indicate anything other than how much of the total energy is useful.  If the 90% efficient fuel has a energy density two orders of magnitude less than the 50% fuel then the 50% is more efficacious in producing energy even though it is less efficient.  If the size of converter and amount of fuel used isn't of concern then both could be considered equally effective at producing a desired energy budget.

Answer (score 12):

You can also use ***utility***, ***usefulness*** or ***usability***.

ODO:

> **[utility](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/utility)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1** The state of being useful, profitable, or beneficial.
>   ‘he had a poor opinion of the utility of book learning’
>
> **[usefulness](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/usefulness)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> The quality or fact of being useful.
>   ‘faults that affect the book's
>   usefulness’
>
> **[usability](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/usability)** (also *useability*)
>   *NOUN*
>
> The degree to which something is able or fit to be used.
>   ‘it was
>   important to measure the usability of each product’

Comment: Anything original here?

Answer (score 7):

One word which does start with a *c* meaning "how well something can do its job" is ***capability***.

> 1. The power or ability to do something.
>
>    *‘he had an intuitive capability of bringing the best out in people’
>
>      ‘the company's capability to increase productivity’*
>
>    1.1 (often *capabilities*) The extent of someone's or something's ability.
>
> — [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/capability)

A similar word is ***capacity:***

> 2.1 The ability or power to do something.
>
> — [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/capacity)

However, since the principal use of *capacity* is to do with *volume,* how much something can contain or hold, using it in the example sentence may not be felicitous.

Comment: I would argue that capability is more a yes/no state... something having the capability to do something doesn't make a statement about how well it does that thing.  I have might have the capability to compete in a marathon but that doesn't say anything about whether I'd make it more than 10m before falling over.

Comment: I think I would call ten metres "limited capability".

Comment: heh, so would I, but then we're in to multiple words.  Actually I'd go for "limited capacity" since it's a duration issue rather than an issue with the ability during the duration, but that's splitting hairs.  "I'm capable of providing that role in a limited capacity" vs "I have limited capabilities in that role"

Answer (score 2):

How about ***effectiveness***?

From [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/effectiveness):

> effective - adjective
>   1. adequate to accomplish a purpose; **producing the intended or expected result**:
>
> > '*effective teaching methods; effective steps toward peace.*'
>
> Related forms: **effectiveness, *noun***

From [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/effectiveness):

> effectiveness - noun
>
> **The degree to which something is successful in producing a desired result**; success.
>
> > *'the effectiveness of the treatment'*

Answer (score 0):

How about mechanics?

> - the machinery or working parts of something. "he looks at the mechanics of a car before the bodywork"
>
>   - the way in which something is done or operated.  "the mechanics of cello playing"

Comment: I was wondering about the relevance of mentioning people who work with machines (mechanics), but the meaning you're using fits quite well with the sample sentence.

Comment: Not so much... the mechanics of performing a specific activity (such as pressing keys) are disconnected from how well that activity is performed.  It's better to think of mechanics in the sense that the rules of a game are the mechanics of how that game is played.  I think it's also the same issue of quality vs quantity, mechanics is like function in relating to position within a quantity operations rather than quality and efficiency in achieving a goal.

Comment: Might be mistaken to mean "the way the thing moves", which is probably a consideration for the item of clothing in the sample sentence–I wouldn't know–but which wouldn't encompass things like ease of use, quality of materials and workmanship, and care instructions.

Answer (score 0):

**comfort**

noun

1. a state of physical ease and freedom from pain or constraint.
   "there is room for four people to travel in comfort"
2. the easing or alleviation of a person's feelings of grief or distress.
   "a few words of comfort"
   synonyms:   consolation, solace, condolence, sympathy, fellow feeling, commiseration;

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for **Quality**.

Specifically, **Good quality**

> https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/good-quality
>
> *Of a high standard.*
> "Use homemade ice cream, or buy a good-quality luxury brand"